# Not understanding a class property

Tags: c#

I'm seeing some code in an approved code review, but not sure what the author was doing. It's a property in a class. Never seen this:

`public IEnumerable<string> XAxisLabels { get => null; set {; } }`

It seems the getter will always return null. And I'm not sure what the setter is doing. What is:
`{ ; }`

The class does have an interface, which has:
`IEnumerable<string> XAxisLabels { get; set; }`

The author, unfortunately, is not contactable anymore.

Seems dangerous:

[image]

Comment: I think it's just a black hole setter. In a code block you can write as many ";"  as you want.

Comment: `;` is the empty statement. It does nothing, so the setter does nothing. The `;` isn't required here though. You could have just done `set {  }`.

Comment: Thanks. So xAxisLabels can never be set... and will always be null, and the getter just returns null? It's just a dummy property, to satisfy the interface?

Comment: @Craig: There is no evidence for an interface in this piece of code. But would be a logical explanation

Comment: Thanks @Klamsi - it does use an interface. I modified my question as that is useful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getter always returns null and setter is doing nothing. Probably interface realisation needs both getter and setter.

Comment: Thanks. So xAxisLabels can never be set... and will always be null, and the getter just returns null? It's just a dummy property, to satisfy the interface?

Comment: Yes it looks like dummy property, check interface which this class implements. If it requires setter - this is correct approach, if not - code can be simplified.

Comment: Interface has ```IEnumerable<string> XAxisLabels { get; set; }``` ... So not sure why we have the null and empty setter. My fear is, if a developer sets that property in code somewhere - it will just be thrown away without the developer's knowledge.

Comment: Maybe throw a NotImplementedException